# WPF windows 8 taskbar swap tiles

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, transform, swap

I am trying to develop drag and drop tile swap movement. It all works fine but the transitions are not smooth. Can anyone help me with smoothing the transitions.

```
<Canvas x:Name="baseCanvas" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove">
        <Label x:Name="label1" Canvas.Left="{Binding XPosition1}" MouseLeftButtonDown="Label_MouseLeftButtonDown" Content="1" Width="40" Height="40" Background="Gray" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" Canvas.Top="47" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="label2" Canvas.Left="{Binding XPosition2}" MouseLeftButtonDown="Label_MouseLeftButtonDown" Content="2" Width="40" Height="40" Background="Gray" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" Canvas.Top="47" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="label3" Canvas.Left="{Binding XPosition3}" MouseLeftButtonDown="Label_MouseLeftButtonDown" Content="3" Width="40" Height="40" Background="Gray" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" Canvas.Top="47" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="label4" Canvas.Left="{Binding XPosition4}" MouseLeftButtonDown="Label_MouseLeftButtonDown" Content="4" Width="40" Height="40" Background="Gray" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" Canvas.Top="47" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="label5" Canvas.Left="{Binding XPosition5}" MouseLeftButtonDown="Label_MouseLeftButtonDown" Content="5" Width="40" Height="40" Background="Gray" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" Canvas.Top="47" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
    </Canvas>
```

It works just like the windows 8 taskbar tiles. Drag transitions are smooth since I constantly update the bound XPosition according to the mouse move location.

```
private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            switch ((e.Source as Label).Content.ToString())
            {
                case "1":
                    movingLocationHelper(Mouse.GetPosition(baseCanvas).X - offset, 1);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    movingLocationHelper(Mouse.GetPosition(baseCanvas).X - offset, 2);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    movingLocationHelper(Mouse.GetPosition(baseCanvas).X - offset, 3);
                    break;
                case "4":
                    movingLocationHelper(Mouse.GetPosition(baseCanvas).X - offset, 4);
                    break;
                case "5":
                    movingLocationHelper(Mouse.GetPosition(baseCanvas).X - offset, 5);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

private void movingLocationHelper(double position, int source)
{

        switch (source)
        {
            case 1:
                XPosition1 = position;
                break;
            case 2:
                XPosition2 = position;
                break;
            case 3:
                XPosition3 = position;
                break;
            case 4:
                XPosition4 = position;
                break;
            case 5:
                XPosition5 = position;
                break;
        }

        position += 20;

        if (position <= position2 - 1)
        {
            swapItems(1, source);
        }
        else if (position2 <= position && position <= position3 - 1)
        {
            swapItems(2, source);
        }
        else if (position3 <= position && position <= position4 - 1)
        {
            swapItems(3, source);
        }
        else if (position4 <= position && position <= position5 - 1)
        {
            swapItems(4, source);
        }
        else if (position5 <= position)
        {
            swapItems(5, source);
        }


    }

private void swapItems(int positionIndex, int movingItem)
    {
        int movingItemPosition = 0;
        int existingItem = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < positionArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(positionArray[i] == movingItem)
            {
                movingItemPosition = i;
            }
        }

        existingItem = positionArray[positionIndex - 1];
        positionArray[positionIndex - 1] = movingItem;
        positionArray[movingItemPosition] = existingItem;

        if (movingItem == 1)
        {
            XPosition2 = findPosition(2);
            XPosition3 = findPosition(3);
            XPosition4 = findPosition(4);
            XPosition5 = findPosition(5);
        }
        else if (movingItem == 2)
        {
            XPosition1 = findPosition(1);
            XPosition3 = findPosition(3);
            XPosition4 = findPosition(4);
            XPosition5 = findPosition(5);
        }
        else if (movingItem == 3)
        {
            XPosition1 = findPosition(1);
            XPosition2 = findPosition(2);                
            XPosition4 = findPosition(4);
            XPosition5 = findPosition(5);
        }
        else if (movingItem == 4)
        {
            XPosition1 = findPosition(1);
            XPosition2 = findPosition(2);
            XPosition3 = findPosition(3);                
            XPosition5 = findPosition(5);
        }
        else if (movingItem == 5)
        {
            XPosition1 = findPosition(1);
            XPosition2 = findPosition(2);
            XPosition3 = findPosition(3);
            XPosition4 = findPosition(4);                
        }
    }
```

so when it comes to swapItems transitions are not smooth since I swap the items by just updating the new XPosition location. I need help animating the swapping part. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG44Y.jpg)

Comment: any luck ? Although I'm using "https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop" gong drag and drop which gives almost smooth transitions